# Arquivo .properties no código java

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Minha aplicação JSF eu estou usando um arquivo .properties para armazenar os textos, etc. Eu já uso chamando as chaves dentro do arquivo .xhtml. Como faço pra chamar as chaves no código .java ?

Minha classe Util:

```
package br.com.pokemax.util;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class MensagensUtil {

    private static final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/mensagens", new Locale("pt_BR"));

    public static String recupera(String chave) {
        return bundle.getString(chave);
    }

    public static void sucesso(String mensagem) {

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, bundle.getString(mensagem), "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", msg);
    }

    public static void erro(String mensagem) {

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, mensagem, "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", msg);
    }

    public static void alerta(String mensagem) {

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, mensagem, "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messagePanel", msg);
    }

}
```

Meu arquivo faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>pt</default-locale>
            <!-- <supported-locale>en</supported-locale> -->
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>properties.mensagens</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

E estou tendo o seguinte erro ao chamar o método sucesso:

```
19:02:21,487 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-6) javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at br.com.pokemax.controle.ControleGeracao.gravar(ControleGeracao.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name resources/mensagens, locale pt_br
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:845)
    at br.com.pokemax.util.MensagensUtil.<clinit>(MensagensUtil.java:11)
    ... 60 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia utilizar o `ResourceBundle`, com ele vc pode acessar os arquivos que se encontram na pasta de resource do sistema. Exemplo:

```
public class ResourceUtil {

    private static ResourceBundle bundle;

    static {
        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages_pt_BR", new Locale("pt_br"));
    }


    public static String recupera(String chave) {
        return bundle.getString(chave);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta chave é o nome do meu arquivo .properties?

Comment: Não, esse é o nome da propriedade que existe arquivo de propriedades. O nome do arquivo nesse exemplo é o `messages_pt_BR`.

Comment: Isso mesmo, no caso dentro do `messages_pt_BR.properties` deveria conter a informação `MSG001=Conteudo da chave.`, por exemplo, para que algo como `recupera("MSG001")` funcione.

Comment: @GustavoCinque adicionei o meu código e olha o erro :(

Comment: @Douglas, por favor, na próxima não faça isso. Finalize essa pergunta, e crie outra. A pergunta teve mudança no escopo. Deixou de ser a mesma pergunta. Provavelmente o seu erro está no arquivo de mensagens, o sistema não consegue encontrar ele dentro de resources, tente retirar `resources\` por que talvez já esteja olhando diretamente na pasta.